# Updating Column In mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help with the code for updating the "Email" column in my database.
the ID column is "UserID" and the Email column is "Email".

```
<form method="POST" action="Index.php" name="UpdateEmail"><div class="input-group">
 <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $Email = $_POST['Email'];
    $EmailID = $_POST['IDhiddenField'];

                mysql_query("UPDATE user SET UserID=$EmailID, Email=$Email WHERE UserID=$EmailID, Email=$Email");


?>      




<?php } ?>


  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email Address Here to Update" type="email" name="Email" required>
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Update Email</button>
    <input name="IDhiddenField" type="hidden" id="IDhiddenField" value="<?php
$my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$id = getuser($my_id, 'UserID'); 
echo "$id";
?>">
  </span>
</div>
  <input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="UpdateEmail">

</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is your concrete question? BTW your code is extremely volunerable for sql injections. Try to use PDO.

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: If you are going to update the rows with the exact same values that match the conditions, you don't need to bother to do anything :-) Apart from that, you should really switch to PDO or mysql and prepared statements to close the sql injection hole you have now.

Comment: nothing will fire up inside your conditional statement; there's a reason. Plus, you're not checking for obvious syntax errors.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I didn't even get that far :-)

Comment: @jeroen that's usually the first thing I look at, when it comes to conditionals ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- The sql already stuck out like a sore thumb for me...

Comment: @jeroen same here. so many  syntax errors. I could easily use that to stitch up my torn up jeans with! Plus, not to mention whether or not they've started the session. I'm not touching this one. I've better things to use my 10 foot pole with.

Comment: @jeroen what does Marc call this type of code again? Cargo something? lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hmmmmm, doesn't ring a bell, the same Marc of *enjoy having your server pwned*?

Comment: @jeroen yep the same Marc. *cargo cult programming* as he calls it. So many unknowns in this question, it's making my pitbull frown and wanting to run away. Ok, I don't have one but if I did, he would. ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Pretty cool description, I wonder if it actually means anything as well :-)

Comment: @jeroen I think I know what he means by that. Something along the lines of, if one gathers all sorts of crazy people around a circle of fire, they're bound to cause trouble in thinking they will achieve the same goal; being trouble while going nowhere. Something along those lines lol *least, that's my take on it.* - I guess it takes one Canuck to figure out another Canuck's thinking.

Answer (score 1):

As they said, you should use PDO, here is a class you can use to do it :
http://pastebin.com/bJcth8rz

You have to make a myPDO.include.php where you set the configuration of your database and include it on each page.

```
$statement = $myPDO::getInstance()->prepare(<<<SQL
    UPDATE user SET Email=:email WHERE UserID=:userID
SQL
);

$email = $_POST['Email'];

$statement->execute(array(":email" => $email,
                          ":userID" => getuser($_SESSION['user_id'],'UserID')));
```

This request will do what you want to BUT.

Be sure you start your session :

```
session_start();
```

When you use sessions, you will have access to it on other pages, you don't have to transfer it by your form with hidden input which can be manipulated by the users !

By the way, I don't understand why do you have an email_ID field, to my mind, your table should be composed by :

```
User
idUser (int)
Email (varchar)
...
```

But i can't get how an email id can be useful here

Comment: this still won't fire up; look at OP's code again *very carefully*.

Comment: By the way, the OP would need `":userID" => getuser($_SESSION['user_id'], 'UserID')` if he ever gets to that line.

Comment: Yeah indeed, but I can't get why the id stored in the $_SESSION isn't the real userID ?

Comment: do you know what a conditional statement does and what a POST array looks for? well, have a look at their code again, and *very carefully* as I previously stated ;-) Plus, we don't even know which MySQL API the OP is actually using to connect with, or whether the OP even knows what to do with your answer. It's the method to use for sure and safer, but I highly doubt the OP knows what to use to connect with it.

Comment: Well, I added myPDO class in my post. Mmh I guess I don't know how a POST array looks for, I just know how to access to the data. :<

Comment: Inspect/analyze this `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`